# convert Closure object to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code:

```
function test($callback) {
    $parameter = func_get_args()[0]["parameter"]; 
    var_dump$parameter);
}

test(function($var, $var2) {});
```

The call generates this error:

> Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type Closure as array

How I can covert the Closure Object to an Array?

I've tried the following things:

```
function test($callback) {
    $parameter = func_get_args()[0];
    $parameter = json_decode(json_encode($parameter), true);
    var_dump($parameter);
}
```

which outputs:

```
array(0) {}
```

and:

```
function test($callback) {
    $parameter = func_get_args()[0];
    $parameter = (array) $parameter;
    var_dump($parameter);
}
```

which outputs:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(Closure)#1 (1) { 
        ["parameter"]=> array(2) { 
             ["$var"]=> string(10) "" 
             ["$var2"]=> string(10) "" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to get an array with parameters of a callback?
If you do, you can use [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

```
function test() {
    $callback = func_get_args()[0];
    $rf = new ReflectionFunction($callback);
    $params = array();
    foreach ($rf->getParameters() as $param) {
        $params[] = $param->getName();
    }
    var_dump($params);
}
```